# how to map old facebook id with new facebook scoped id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im using FB App for my site, in that FB announced that graph api, new api will return app scoped id instead of fb user_id. I used to store all my FB user_id to table and retrieve data for next time by matching user_id.

Now new api will provide scoped_id its new to all users so how can i figure out this user is already register in our site?

Simply, how to find out the user is already logged with us by comparing or getting user_id ?

how can i get user_id by passing scoped_user_id ?

Answer (score 2):

I think mapping is not necessary, have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app, the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into your app. This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has logged into your app at any point in the past.